# Show that $\frac{(5+4\sqrt x)^2}{2x}=\frac{25}{2x}+\frac P{\sqrt x}+Q$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{(5+4\sqrt x)^2}{2x}=\frac{25}{2x}+\frac P{\sqrt x}+Q$$
I can simplify the brackets into $\frac{25+40\sqrt x+16x}{2x}$. Yet in the marking scheme they write this instead:
$$\frac12x^{-1}(25+40\sqrt x+16x)$$
Why do they do this?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you wrote. Try MathJaX, this site's official language. There are instructions somewhere.

Comment: *possibly* Show $\dfrac{(5+4\sqrt{x})^2}{2x} = \dfrac{25}2 x^{-1} +Px^{ -1/2} + Q$

Comment: If you have $\dfrac{25+ 40\sqrt{x}+16x}{2x}$ then try  $\dfrac{25}{2x}+\dfrac{40\sqrt{x}}{2x}+\dfrac{16x}{2x}$ next

Comment: @DonAntonio Right, I had to "interpret" the ASCII maths.

Answer (score 1):

Fractions' rules: $\;\cfrac{a+b}c=\cfrac ac+\cfrac bc\;$, and thus

$$\frac{(5+4\sqrt x)^2}{2x}=\frac{25+40\sqrt x+16x}{2x}=\frac{25}{2x}+\frac{40\sqrt x}{2x}+\frac{16}{2x}=\frac{25}{2x}+\frac{20}{\sqrt x}+2$$

Remember also: for **any** two $\;n,m\in\Bbb R\;$ , we have that $\;\cfrac{x^m}{x^n}=x^{m-n}=\cfrac1{x^{n-m}}\;$